# PyQt QProcess started twice & QProcess: Destroyed while process is still running error

Tags: pyqt, qprocess

I'm trying to get some pyqt thread pools and process working but have run into a few issues and was wondering if anyone could help.
I've simplified the code down and have included it here. 
When you run the following it seems the `started()` method seems to get called twice for each process which isn't something I'd expect.

Also, I get the error `QProcess: Destroyed` while process is still running.
Can anyone enlighten me as to why this occurs?
Running `startDetached()` enables the code to work but because it doesn't return an object I lose all ability to use signals.
Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks a lot

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui,QtCore

class Test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.elements = []
        for i in range(5):
            self.elements.append(Element(i))

    def run(self):                                                                                                 
        pool = QtCore.QThreadPool()                                                                                
        pool.setMaxThreadCount(1)

        for element in self.elements:
            pool.start(element.worker)                                                                        

        pool.waitForDone()


class Worker(QtCore.QRunnable):
    def __init__(self):                                                                                            
        super(Worker, self).__init__()                                                                             


class Element(object):                                                                                         

    def __init__(self, number):
        self.number = number

        self.worker = Worker()
        self.worker.run = self.run

    def run(self):
        process = QtCore.QProcess()
        def started():
            print "Started"

        process.started.connect(started)
        process.start('echo', 'hello')

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

test = Test()
test.run()

widget = QtGui.QWidget()
widget.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: You are getting `QProcess: Destroyed` errors because `process` is deleted after the `run()` method returns. Make it a member of `Element` to avoid this.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That stops me getting the error but it now doesn't seem to hook up to started() at all. Any ideas?

Comment: Ok ... so using self.process.waitForFinished() allows the signals to work

Comment: I suspect that this happens for the same reason - `started()` is only defined while the program is inside of `run()`. Adding `self.process.waitForFinished()` will wait inside of `run()` until the process is finished. Is there any reason why you don't define `started()` as a member of the class also?